# Exception order

Tags: java

This is one question in the quiz that I am confusing.
Given the code fragment:

```
public void foo(){
    try{
        System.out.println(“starting”);
        bar();
        System.out.println(“passed bar”);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(“foo exception”);
}
```

Give the output for the method foo() above IF bar() throws an exception

My answer was:

starting

foo exception

Is that correct?

Could you please show me how can I test it or explain it to me?
Thank you very much for your help!!

I get it now, 
Thank you so much for very quick and helpful responses

Comment: It rather depends whether bar outputs anything before throwing the exception.

Comment: in addition to Pete Kirkham, also depends on in bar method you catch any exception.

Comment: Did you forget the first end bracket? you're closing try but not closing the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        bar();
        System.out.println("passed bar");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("foo exception");
    }
}

private static void bar() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Output as expected:

> Starting
>   foo exception

The first line will be shown as expected. After that it goes to `bar()` which throws an error and immediatly continues in the `catch` block. This block outputs the second message.

Comment: what if i catch the exception in bar method?

Comment: Then no exception will be thrown in the main try-catch. "Passed bar" will be shown instead of "foo exception". Surely you can try this yourself with the code I gave you

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the first `println` will simply run with no problems, then `bar` runs and throws an Exception, because you have contained it within a `try` and have covered all types of exceptions with the most abstract exception (`Exception` type) so all type of exceptions will be caught, when this happens the `catch` code block will run (meaning "foo exception" will be printed), and the program will continue anything after as usual. Because it was caught the second `println` will never run.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this by writing the `bar()` method yourself :p

```
void bar() throws Exception {
  throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeroen Vannevel's answer the following code outputs as:

```
Starting
i catched an exception in bar()
passed bar
```

.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting");
            bar();
            System.out.println("passed bar");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("foo exception");
        }
    }

    private static void bar() throws Exception {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("i catched an exception in bar()");
        }
    }
```